# SQL Server - Cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-cursor

I am trying to loop through a table using a cursor:

```
DEClARE @ProjectOID as nvarchar (100)
DECLARE @TaskOID as nvarchar (100)
DECLARE TaskOID_Cursor FOR
SELECT  TaskOID FROM ProjectOID_Temp
OPEN TaskOID_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TaskOID_Cursor INTO @TaskOID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT t1.OID as taskResourceOID, t2.OID as EvUserOID
    FROM (select OID, resourceOID from taskresourcehours 
    where projecttaskoid =   @TaskOID) as t1,
    (
     select OID, workerOID
     from Evuser
     where workerOID in
      ( select resourceOID from taskresourcehours where projecttaskoid = @TaskOID )
    ) as t2
    WHERE t1.resourceOID = t2.workerOID
FETCH NEXT FROM TaskOID_Cursor
INTO @TaskOID
END
CLOSE TaskOID_Cursor
DEALLOCATE TaskOID_Cursor
```

That above returns taskResourceOID and EvUserOID. If I need to output a table with the @TaskOID and the respective taskResourceOID and EvUserOID, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: You have a syntax error at `DECLARE TaskOID_Cursor FOR`, missing type

Comment: Why are you using a cursors instead of a normal join, when a normal join would be so much faster?

Comment: "what is the best way to do it?" Don't use a cursor. Looks like you should be able to do this without.

Comment: @Matten: This should read `DECLARE TaskOID_Cursor CURSOR FOR`

Comment: @Throsten, yes that is correct. I am sorry I typed it wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a temporary table or a table variable..

```
DEClARE @ProjectOID as nvarchar (100)
DECLARE @TaskOID as nvarchar (100)
DECLARE @retTable TABLE (
  TaskOID nvarchar(100),
  TaskResourceOID nvarchar(100),
  EvUserOID nvarchar(100)
)
DECLARE TaskOID_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT  TaskOID FROM ProjectOID_Temp
OPEN TaskOID_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TaskOID_Cursor INTO @TaskOID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @retTable
      SELECT @TaskOID,t1.OID as TaskResourceOID, t2.OID as EvUserOID
      FROM (
        select OID, resourceOID from taskresourcehours 
        where projecttaskoid =   @TaskOID) as t1,
        ( 
          select OID, workerOID
          from Evuser
        and workerOID in -- this must be AND and not a second WHERE
          ( select resourceOID from taskresourcehours where projecttaskoid = @TaskOID )
        ) as t2
      WHERE t1.resourceOID = t2.workerOID
FETCH NEXT FROM TaskOID_Cursor
INTO @TaskOID
END
CLOSE TaskOID_Cursor
DEALLOCATE TaskOID_Cursor

SELECT * FROM @retTable
```

**Or even better, don't use a cursor (this can be performed as a select, but I leave this up to you... Just wanted to show how to use a cursor AND a table as return value)**

Comment: Hi Matten - this is part of a multi step approach to fix some errors in the data as per the application vendor guidelines. Is there a way to insert @TaskOID too to the output table along with TaskResourceOID and EvUserOID. I am looking for a temp table which has TaskOID|TaskResourceOID|EvUserOID

Comment: @RK Kuppala no problem, just add it to the table (i've adopted my answer to your edit)

Answer (score 3):

Without having tested, this should work without using a cursor:

```
DECLARE @retTable TABLE (
  TaskResourceOID nvarchar(100),
  EvUserOID nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @retTable
SELECT 
    t1.OID as taskResourceOID, 
    t2.OID as EvUserOID
FROM 
  ProjectOID_Temp pt,
  (select OID from taskresourcehours where projecttaskoid = pt.TaskOID) as t1,
  (select OID from Evuser where workerOID in (select resourceOID from taskresourcehours where projecttaskoid = pt.TaskOID)) as t2
WHERE t1.resourceOID = t2.workerOID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
USE [Demo_03]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Salrafer_BiACT_SOr]    Script Date: 06-Apr-2021 11:32:25 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



-- =============================================

-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SaTsfer_Bind_SOthr]
(
@SalaryDate DATE=NULL
)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE 
@EmpCode bigint=null,
   



CREATE TABLE #TempSalaDetail
(
    EmpCode bigint,
    

)


/**End Region**/
/**Create Temp Table For Fetch Billing Details For Reports**/
CREATE TABLE #TempFinalSalaryDetail
(   
    EmpCode bigint,
    EmpName nvarchar(500),
    
    
    
)
/**End Region**/



DECLARE @TempSiteCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @TempSiteFinalCursor CURSOR



INSERT INTO #TempSalaryDetail
(
    EmpCode
)
(

SELECT EmpCode,
FROm tbl_SalRegi WHERE 

)



    
SET @TempSiteFinalCursor=CURSOR FOR SELECT EmpCodeFROM #TempSalaryDetail
OPEN @TempSiteFinalCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @TempSiteFinalCursor INTO @EmpCode

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        
        
        
        

        
        SET @AccountNo=(SELECT AccountNo FROM tbl_Emps_Account WHERE EmpAccId=@EmpAcId )
        

        

    
        INSERT INTO #TempFinalSalaryDetail
        (       
            EmpCode,
            
            
        )
        VALUES
        (
         
          @EmpCode,
          
        
         
        )
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM @TempSiteFinalCursor INTO @EmpCode,
    END
    
SELECT  EmpCode,
            EmpName,
            
FROM #TempFinalSalaryDetail
order by case when BankId=1 then 0 else 2 end, BankId asc, EmpCode asc


DEALLOCATE @TempSiteFinalCursor

DROP TABLE #TempSalaryDetail
DROP TABLE #TempFinalSalaryDetail
END
```